permanently deleting contact does not remove relationships
When a contact is permanently deleted, the relationships remain in the civicrm_relationship talbe (i.e., they don't get deleted/removed), which then causes issues when the relationship cache table rebuild runs, i.e., it completely farts, and doesn't get built, causing all sorts of issues. Is that just our instance where that happens? Or, are others seeing the same behavior? If so, that's a design flaw, no?

You're probably missing a foreign key in your schema. I'm not seeing it work like you describe, and if you SHOW CREATE TABLE civicrm_relationship, do you see these?
CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_relationship_contact_id_a` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id_a`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_relationship_contact_id_b` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id_b`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,


Thank you, Demerit, I do see those FK's in the civicrm_relationship table. Should there be some in the civicrm_contact table, as well?

No there shouldn't be anything related in the contact table, but that's weird that you have them and are still having the problem, because when the contact is removed from the contact table those key constraints should remove the relationship record.
